# How do I add rounded corners to a GridView table in my .net code?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, css, gridview

I've tried adding webkit border radius / moz border radius / border radius to both the css definition and the .net definition, but to no avail. Help!

```
<tr>
    <td width="60%" align="center">
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView_VE" runat="server" CssClass="table1" HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="80%"   
        OnPageIndexChanging="GridView_VE_PageIndexChanging" Font-Names="Century Gothic" Font-Size="Large" Height="100%"
        AllowPaging="True" PageSize="4" RowStyle-Height="30px" -webkit-border-radius= "10px" -moz-border-radius="10px"
        border-radius="10px" border="2px" border-color="Black">
            <Columns>
            ...
            </Columns>
            <PagerStyle Height="20px" />
            <RowStyle Wrap="True" />
         </asp:GridView>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I've tried implementing the corners to the td , tr and table too. But again, fail.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Wrap the `<asp:GridView>` in a div and then place the rounded corners on that div.

```
<div class="rounded-corners">
    <asp:GridView>....</asp:GridView>
</div>
```

And the CSS

```
.rounded-corners {
  border: 1px solid black;
  -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
  -moz-border-radius: 8px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Justin. It didn't work though, it only created a slightly larger rounded box in the background of the table. The square corners of the inner table still stick out. Sigh.

Comment: add `overflow: hidden` to the .rounded-corners CSS. See if that helps the square corners of the inner table sticking out.

Answer (score 1):

You should wrap your style elements inside a `style=""` element. Like so: 
`<table style="border-radius: 8px; -moz-border-radius: 8px; -webkit-border-radius: 8px;">`

BUT it might be better to only set border-radius on the first and last row.

Anyway, here are a couple of options: http://jsfiddle.net/wMGnq/

Oh, and also make sure that border-collapse is not set to collapse! See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/border-radius

Comment: Thanks Bram! Didnt work yo. Tried putting the style elements in both table and the corresponding css sheet (header/footer and otherwise), but nada.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a problem, just give your table class and add following css:

```
.bordered {
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    border-radius: 6px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Morpheus. Adding a css class didnt help. BUT, wrapping the GridView in a div with the css class helped.